# Eclipse does not see my c++ includes from separate folders

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

I have the folowing folder file hierarchy:

```
src/
  Fuelable.h
  Fuelables/
    PetrolCar.h
    PetrolCar.cpp
```

**PetrolCar.h:**

```
#include "Fuelable.h"
```

**PetrolCar.cpp:**

```
#include "PetrolCar.h"
```

In order to make this compile i added src folder to include paths as in this manual:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm

The include code is not highlighted as error. But when i am trying to build it fails with error concerning makefile:

```
Building file: ../src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.cpp
In file included from ../src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.cpp:8:0:
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
../src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.h:12:22: fatal error: Fuelable.h: No such file or directory
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.d" -MT"src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.d" -o "src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.o" "../src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.cpp"
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/Fuelables/PetrolCar.o]
```

What is interesting, **the intellisence sees all the files**.

If I compile from command line:

```
sashko@sashko-1225C:~/workspaceEclipse/FuelingSystem/src/Fuelables$ g++ PetrolCar.cpp -I 
/home/sashko/workspaceEclipse/FuelingSystem/src/Fuelable.h
cc1plus: warning: /home/sashko/workspaceEclipse/FuelingSystem/src/Fuelable.h: not a directory [enabled by default]
In file included from PetrolCar.cpp:8:0:
PetrolCar.h:12:22: fatal error: Fuelable.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Compile on the command line. Add appropriate `-I` options to `g++`

Comment: have you tried `#include "../Fuelable.h"` to specify that the file is in the previous directory?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, what do mean by appropriate? Updated question.

Comment: @Gmercer015 I did but I heared it is a bad style. Besides what if I want to include a file wich is far far away e.g.: "ProjectFolder/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you would distribute a library Machines. The include  hierarchy could be:

```
some_local_or_general_or_system_include_directory
- Machines
  - Fuelables
```

Then you can `#include <Machines/Fuelable.h>` or `#include <Machines/Fuelables/PetrolCar.h>` having a single include directory. Otherwise, you have to add each directory to your include path.

Comment: Fuelable.h is an interface to implementation classes in folder "Fuelables". I can't nest folders as you suggest.